# Can't delete an edge

Tags: 3d, maya

I'm new to Maya. I mirrored my box, combined and merged the pieces and tried to delete edges in the middle. I see in the channel box that the application registers the command, but edges won't delete. What may be the reason?

[image: The box]

[image: Channel box]

[image: Outliner]

Comment: Just a hunch, but try deleting the edges twice. When you put the two halves together `[ ] + [ ]`, it may be the case that there's technically two edges at the seam (one from each half), so it may be that you're deleting one, but still seeing the second.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I forgot to mention, that I mirrored the two sides the old-fashioned way: duplicate, translate -1 on X, combine and merge. Interestingly, if I'd deleted the top faces, I could see the face in the middle that wouldn't delete with the delete key but could be deleted from the Outliner.  After that, I deleted the face before translating it to -1 on X, then rotated the second half and merged the pieces. The Mirror function worked fine right away, though.

Comment: You're welcome - but I'm not totally clear as to if my suggestion lead you to a successful conclusion. If it did, I encourage you to summarize the steps you took & post them as answer. I made my suggestion as a comment because I've not actually used Maya - I just made an educated guess. Posting your solution as an answer post helps others with similar problems discover your answer. If my suggestion didn't help you find a solution, please edit your question indicating why that does work (reduces the chance other suggest the same thing). Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Unfortunately, it did not. I tried to delete the edges several times to no avail. Still don't know what caused the issue, so can't write down the answer :(